# how do I check for errors when calling os.Open(<filename>) in Go?

Tags: coding-style, go

I'm new to Go (spent 30mins so far!) and am trying to do File I/O.

```
  file, ok := os.Open("../../sample.txt")
  if ok != nil {
    // error handling code here
    os.Exit(1)
  }
  ...
```

When the call fails, shouldn't it return an error number? This call returns os.Error and it has no methods other than 'String()'.

Is this the *recommended* way to check for errors in Go?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typical Go code (which uses the `os` package) is not analyzing the returned error object. It just prints the error message to the user (who then knows what went wrong based on the printed message) or returns the error *as-is* to the caller.

If you want to prevent your program from opening a non-existent file, or want to check whether the file is readable/writable, I wound suggest to use the [os.Stat](http://golang.org/pkg/os/#Stat) function prior to opening the file.

Your can analyze the Go type of the returned error, but this seems inconvenient:

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "os"

func main() {
    _, err := os.Open("non-existent")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("err has type %T\n", err)
        if err2, ok := err.(*os.PathError); ok {
            fmt.Printf("err2 has type %T\n", err2.Error)
            if errno, ok := err2.Error.(os.Errno); ok {
                fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "errno=%d\n", int64(errno))
            }
        }

        fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "%s\n", err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }
}
```

which prints:

```
err has type *os.PathError
err2 has type os.Errno
errno=2
open non-existent: no such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is the normal way in Go (multi-value return), the makers of Go have a different view on Exceptions and handle it in this way.

Read this:

http://www.softmachinecubed.com/tech/2009/12/6/googles-go-language-multi-value-return-vs-exceptions-c.html

Comment: thanks! what if I wanted to do something specific when the error is because the file exists but not readable? or something different when the file doesn't exist?